# CRTP sub-subclass and instances list

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, static-members, crtp

I'm trying to implement a kind of CRTP (if I well understand what it is) with multiple inheritance.

My main goal is to have a unified way to access list of instances of each subclass.

May problem seems to reside in the namespace utilization.

Here is the code of the simplest version :
http://ideone.com/rFab5

My real problem is more similar to :
http://ideone.com/U7cAf

I have an additional warning using clang++ :

```
test.cpp:28:63: warning: static data member specialization of 'instances' must originally be declared in namespace 'NS1'; accepted as a C++0x extension [-Wc++0x-extensions]
template <> std::list<NS1::Derived*> NS1::Base<NS1::Derived>::instances;
                                                          ^ 
test.cpp:15:34: note: explicitly specialized declaration is here
        static std::list<T*> instances;
```

*Problem has been updated since it does not behave the same using namespaces.*

*Problem re-edited to post code on Ideone*

Comment: Why do you need to reinit the instance-list?

Comment: I have to init it for each final subclass because I want it to be a list of the final subclass. Notice that in the second method using Intermediary class, I don't init the list in the Intermediary implementation.

Comment: is it linker problem or compiler error? it seems even if you pass compiler errors you might get linker problems due to your defenition.

Comment: It is a compiler error, though g++ doesn't give any error before the linkage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've tried to define the list variable wrong. You need to provide a definition for Base, in general- you don't just define it for the one part that happens to be Derived's subclass, unless it's an explicit specialization.

```
template<typename T> std::list<T*> NS1::Base<T>::instances;
```

http://ideone.com/Vclac

Compiles with no errors. There are no intermediates or anything like that required.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `Base()` and `Intermediary()` to `Base<U>()` and `Intermediary<Derived>` in the constructors makes the code [OK](http://ideone.com/u62Sb) for GCC.

There is no reason to change the definition of `instances` in the second case: the template is identical as the first situation.

Comment: That does not change my problem, in fact I added the type specifier in my code but forget to write it here because clang++ uses auto-typing.

Comment: @Geoffroy Then I don't know what is your problem because your code works? How is my snippet different than what is posted in your question?

Comment: I updated my problem, adding namespaces. I didn't though it would change something.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, you got the following options.
First, if `Intermediate` is always templated on the derived type, you don't need a list for it, because it will never be the most derived type. If it could be templated on other types / not be derived, you can add a defaulted non-type bool template parameter like so:

```
template<bool, class A, class B>
struct select_base{
  typedef A type;
};

template<class A, class B>
struct select_base<false,A,B>{
  typedef B type;
};

template<class T, bool IsDerived = false>
class Intermediate
  : public select_base<IsDerived,
                       Base<T>,
                       Base<Intermediate<T> >
                       >::type
{
  // ...
};

// derived use
class Derived : public Intermediate<Derived, true>
{
  // ...
};

// non-derived use:
Intermediate<int> im;
```

If the intermediate class is not templated and does not already derive from `Base`, you need to derive from `Base` again in the most derived class:

```
class Derived : public Intermediate, public Base<Derived>
{
  // ...
};
```

The big problem comes when the intermediate also derives from `Base` but is not templated. You can add a defaulted derived type, but that would make the non-derived use a bit more ugly:

```
#include <type_traits> // C++0x, use std::
//#include <tr1/type_traits> // C++03, use std::tr1::

struct nil_base{};

template<class Derived = nil_base>
class Intermediate
  : public select_base<std::is_same<Derived,nil_base>::value,
                       Base<Intermediate<Derived> >, //
                       Base<Derived>
                       >::type
{
  // ...
};

// derived use now without boolean flag
class Derived : public Intermediate<Derived>
{
  // ...
};

// non-derived use a bit uglier
Intermediate<> im;
//          ^^ -- sadly needed
```

Comment: I updated my problem, adding namespaces. I didn't though it would change something.

Answer (score 0):

The following compiles OK with MinGW g++ 4.4.1, MSVC 10.0, and Comeau Online 4.3.10.1:

```
#include <list>

template <class T>
class Base
{
protected:
    Base()
    {
        instances.push_back(static_cast<T*>(this));
    }
private:
    static std::list<T*> instances;
};

template <class U>
class Intermediary : public Base<U>
{
protected:
    Intermediary()
    :Base<U>()
    {
    }
};

class Derived : public Intermediary<Derived>
{
public:
    Derived()
    :Intermediary<Derived>()
    {
    }
};

template<class Derived> std::list<Derived*> Base<Derived>::instances;

int main()
{}
```

The `instances` definition is copied verbatim from your question.

I say as Isaac Newton, I frame no hypotheses!

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I updated my problem, adding namespaces. I didn't though it would change something.